# How to show just one value result (full outer join)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Table and field info as below.

```html
Item ID (Column : Item ID / Desc)
=====================
Item ID      Desc
0001 --------  A
0002 --------  B
0003 -------- null

Price Table (Column : Item ID  / Price Level(lvl)  / Price)
=========================================
Item ID      Price Level           Price
0001  -----------  1   -------------3.99
0001  -----------  2   -------------1.99
0002  -----------  1   -------------2.99
0003  -----------  1   -------------5.99
0003  -----------  2   -------------3.99
```

(Default Price Level is "1")
so, Every item got the price level 1, some item got the price level 1 and 2

I use the full outer join 'Item' and 'Price' table.

```html
select trs_itm.id, item.desc, price.lvl, price.price from trs_itm
full outer join item on trs_itm.id = item.id
full outer join price on price.id = item.id
group by trs_itm.id, item.desc, price.lvl, price.price
```

How to show the result of the query as below.

If some item has a price level '2', just show result price level 2.
but the item hasn't price level '2', just show default price level 1.

please, help me.

```html
==============================================
ID        Desc    lvl       price
0001 ------ A ---- 2 -------1.99
0002 ------ B ---- 1 -------2.99
0003 -----null --- 2 -------3.99
```

Comment: Your code mentions 3 tables not 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you are doing a full outer join in this case.
Join the 2 tables and the query that returns the max price level for each item:

```
select i.*, p.pricelevel, p.price
from item i 
inner join price p on p.itemid = i.itemid
inner join (
  select itemid, max(pricelevel) pricelevel
  from price
  group by itemid
) g on g.itemid = p.itemid and g.pricelevel = p.pricelevel
order by i.itemid
```

Or with `not exists`:

```
select i.*, p.pricelevel, p.price
from item i inner join (
  select p.* from price p
  where not exists (
    select 1 from price
    where itemid = p.itemid and pricelevel > p.pricelevel 
  )
) p on p.itemid = i.itemid
order by i.itemid
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0975aa140b3d08b6b8b53641c5be21a9).
Results:

```
> itemid | desc | pricelevel | price
> -----: | :--- | ---------: | ----:
>      1 | A    |          2 |  1.99
>      2 | B    |          1 |  2.99
>      3 | null |          2 |  3.99
```